# Child thread not starting

Tags: java, multithreading

I have created a GUI for starting a Thread which does something very simple. However, the child thread never starts.

The child thread, if started, will give some output; I don't get any output though. What am I missing?

Here's the Code:

1. The GUI class:

   ```
   import java.awt.FlowLayout;
   import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
   import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
   import javax.swing.JButton;
   import javax.swing.JFrame;


   public class gui {
       public static void main(String [] args) {           
           //final standalone s = new standalone();
           final try2 t= new try2();

           JFrame win = new JFrame();
           win.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

           JButton start = new JButton("Start");
           JButton stop = new JButton("Stop");

           start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   t.t.start();
                   System.out.println("M on!");
                   try{
                   Thread.currentThread().sleep(10000);
                   }catch(Exception e1)
                   {
                       e1.printStackTrace();
                   }
                   System.out.println("M off!");
                   if(t.t.isInterrupted())
                       System.out.println("Stopped");
               }
           });         

           win.add(start);
           win.add(stop);

           win.setVisible(true);
       }
   }
   ```
2. And here is the Child Thread

   ```
   public class try2 implements Runnable {
       public Thread t;
       int i;

       try2() {
           t=new Thread();             
       }

       public void run() {
           System.out.println(++i);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Offtopic friendly advice: read about Java naming conventions. Classes should be named `LikeThisName`, not `likethisname`.

Comment: You didn't override the run method in try2.t

Comment: Instead of sleeping for 10 seconds, you can join() on the thread to wait for it to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your class try2 extends `Thread` (and remove the implements `Runnable`)., then simply call `start()` on your try2 instance.

Comment: Extending `Thread` is not the best practice. You should rather implement `Runnable` and put it into `Thread`'s constructor. Here's explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/java-implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread

Comment: That would be my preference too, but for such a simple case, it is a bit of an overkill.

Comment: Not really. Instead of `threadObject.start()` you write `new Thread(runnableObject).start()`. Not that much of an overkill. An overkill would be using `ExecutorService` (which is actually preferred) for such simple task.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `t.t.start()` it is starting the thread object in the `t` field of your `try2` object.  Unfortunately, this Thread has no `Runnable`, so when you start it, it will exit immediately.  The `try2.run()` method is not called because the thread knows nothing about it.

Your code is convoluted.  I'd simplify / fix it as follows:

1. Get rid of the `try2.t` field.
2. In the `actionPerformed` method create and run the thread as follows:

   ```
     new Thread(t).start();
   ```

   where `t` is your `try2` instance.

And while you are fixing the code, `try2` violates all Java style guides that I've ever come across.  Class names should always start with a capital letter.  Get into the habit of doing it right ...

Answer (score 0):

Your class try2 should extend Thread (and implement the method run())
The way you are dealing with it, yuo are calling the run()-method of the thread-Object t inside try2. But the run()-method of this object is empty.

Comment: Extending `Thread` is a bad idea. Implementing `Runnable` is a preferred way. More info on that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/java-implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread